# Rolling your own reduceByKey in Spark Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

I'm trying to learn to use DataFrames and DataSets more in addition to RDDs.  For an RDD, I know I can do `someRDD.reduceByKey((x,y) => x + y)`, but I don't see that function for Dataset.  So I decided to write one.

```
someRdd.map(x => ((x.fromId,x.toId),1)).map(x => collection.mutable.Map(x)).reduce((x,y) => {
  val result = mutable.HashMap.empty[(Long,Long),Int]
  val keys = mutable.HashSet.empty[(Long,Long)]
  y.keys.foreach(z => keys += z)
  x.keys.foreach(z => keys += z)
  for (elem <- keys) {
    val s1 = if(x.contains(elem)) x(elem) else 0
    val s2 = if(y.contains(elem)) y(elem) else 0
    result(elem) = s1 + s2
  }
  result
})
```

However, this returns everything to the driver.  How would you write this to return a `Dataset`?  Maybe mapPartition and do it there?

Note this compiles but does not run because it doesn't have encoders for `Map` yet

Comment: with Spark 2.0.0, try this , yourDataset.groupByKey(...).reduceGroups(...)

Comment: Will the catalyst optimizer notice you're doing a group followed by a reduce and make it more efficient?  By 'efficient' I mean in terms of how on an RDD doing a reduce by key is better than doing a group by then reduce by?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I assume your goal is to translate this idiom to Datasets:

```
rdd.map(x => (x.someKey, x.someField))
   .reduceByKey(_ + _)

// => returning an RDD of (KeyType, FieldType)
```

Currently, the closest solution I have found with the Dataset API looks like this:

```
ds.map(x => (x.someKey, x.someField))          // [1]
  .groupByKey(_._1)                            
  .reduceGroups((a, b) => (a._1, a._2 + b._2))
  .map(_._2)                                   // [2]

// => returning a Dataset of (KeyType, FieldType)

// Comments:
// [1] As far as I can see, having a map before groupByKey is required
//     to end up with the proper type in reduceGroups. After all, we do
//     not want to reduce over the original type, but the FieldType.
// [2] required since reduceGroups converts back to Dataset[(K, V)]
//     not knowing that our V's are already key-value pairs.
```

Doesn't look very elegant and according to a quick benchmark it is also much less performant, so maybe we are missing something here...

Note: An alternative might be to use `groupByKey(_.someKey)` as a first step. The problem is that using `groupByKey` changes the type from a regular `Dataset` to a [`KeyValueGroupedDataset`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset). The latter does not have a regular `map` function. Instead it offers an `mapGroups`, which does not seem very convenient because it wraps the values into an `Iterator` and performs a shuffle according to the docstring.

Comment: This does the trick.  Just a note though, reduceByKey is more efficient because it reduces on each node before shuffling.  Doing groupByKey first shuffles all the elements then starts reducing.  That is why its much less performant.  Whats funny is that this is what I used to do before I knew about reduceByKey but I had forgotten :-)

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas I have read on the interwebs that Datasets take advantage of Sparks' Catalyst Optimizer, and should be able to push down the reduce function before shuffling. This may explain why there is no `reduceByKey` in the `Dataset` API. However, in my experience this is not the case and `groupByKey.reduceGroups` shuffles significantly more data and is significantly slower than `reduceByKey`.

Comment: Seems that reduceGroups performance has been fixed from 2.0.1 & 2.1.0 [Spark-16391](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16391)

Comment: Ah, yeah.  From the sounds of it, it looks like it works just like reduceByKey now.  Do you know if there are any plans to implement reduceByKey?  This technically works but is much more verbose.

Comment: This solution works for me, thanks!  But I have a question: any idea why `reduceByKey` doesn't support pattern matching?  For clarity, I would like to be able to write `reduceByKey{ case ((k1, v1), (k2, v2)) => (k1, v1 + v2) }`, but the compiler doesn't like it, even if I add type annotation on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 9):

A more efficient solution uses `mapPartitions` before `groupByKey` to reduce the amount of shuffling (note this is not the exact same signature as `reduceByKey` but I think it is more flexible to pass a function than require the dataset consist of a tuple).

```
def reduceByKey[V: ClassTag, K](ds: Dataset[V], f: V => K, g: (V, V) => V)
  (implicit encK: Encoder[K], encV: Encoder[V]): Dataset[(K, V)] = {
  def h[V: ClassTag, K](f: V => K, g: (V, V) => V, iter: Iterator[V]): Iterator[V] = {
    iter.toArray.groupBy(f).mapValues(_.reduce(g)).map(_._2).toIterator
  }
  ds.mapPartitions(h(f, g, _))
    .groupByKey(f)(encK)
    .reduceGroups(g)
}
```

Depending on the shape/size of your data, this is within 1 second of the performance of `reduceByKey`, and about `2x` as fast as a `groupByKey(_._1).reduceGroups`. There is still room for improvements, so suggestions would be welcome.