# Spark containers killed by YARN during group by

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a data set extracted from Hbase, which is a long form of wide table, i.e has `rowKey`, `columnQualifier` and `value` columns. To get a form of pivot, I need to group by `rowKey`, which is a string UUID, into a collection and make an object out of the collection. The problem is that only group-by I manage to perform is count the number of elements in groups; other group-bys fail due to container being kill due to memory overflow beyond YARN container limits. I did experiment a lot with the memory sizes, including overhead, partitioning with and without sorting etc. I went even into a high number of partitions i.e. about 10 000 but the job dies the same. I tried both DataFrame `groupBy` and `collect_list`, as well as Dataset `grouByKey` and `mapGroups`.

The code works on a small data set but not on the larger one. The data set is about 500 GB in Parquet files. The data is not skewed as the largest group in group by have only 50 elements. Thus, by all known to me means the partitions should easily fit in memory as the aggregated data per one `rowKey` is not really large. The data keys and values are mostly strings and there are not long.

I am using Spark 2.0.2; the above computations were all done is Scala.

Comment: Have you increased the executors memory ? If so, by how much ?

Comment: Yes, as I said I did a lot of experimentation including executor memory and overhead, number of executors and cores, partitions etc. The problem is also not skewed, which is the usual suspect in the case of grouping.

Comment: Have you tried `reduceByKey` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running into the dreaded `groupByKey` shuffle.  Please read this Databricks article on [avoiding groupByKey](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html), which details the underlying differences between the two functions.

If you don't want the read the article, the short story is this:  Though `groupByKey` and `reduceByKey` produce the same results, `groupByKey` instantiates a shuffle of ALL data, while `reduceByKey` tries to minimize data shuffle by reducing first.  A bit like MapReduce `Combiners`, if you're familiar with that concept.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I know the article and how it works. In this case the problem is quite bounded, thus, I thought this `groupBy` shouldn't be that expensive. I have not tried `reduceByKey`, I will give it a go. Nonetheless, in case of my problem I either have to either use `Map[String,Any]` or use reflection to pack single values into a large object and create a notion of sum.

Interestingly, also using DataFrame function `collect_list`, which should be optimal and presumably avoids `groupByKey` throws the same error.

Comment: I have rebuild the job using `reduceByKey` approach and it is more optimal, despite the fact that I'm concatenating maps.  It can be done in `Dataset` using operations `groupByKey` and `reduceGroups` or `mapGroups`, but it is not so optimal: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383207/rolling-your-own-reducebyke-in-spark-dataset)